# Save D3 svg as a high quality image - viewport case

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to save a d3 svg as a high quality png image based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492000/save-d3-svg-as-a-high-quality-image) topic.

The problem is that my svg is a responsive one, so it has no width and height attributes. As a result the final png doesnt look right (the width / height ratio is not right).

I ended up trying to make a new svg element, with the correct width and height attributes and continue with this one, but it seems that I am doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var   w = 193,
      h = 260;
var ratio = 2;
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas1.id = "canvas1";
canvas1.width = w * 2.0;
canvas1.height = h * 2.0;
document.getElementById('pngcon').appendChild(canvas1);

var svg = document.getElementById(`chartId`).querySelector('svg');

var step = document.createElement('svg');
    step.id = 'newsvg';
    step.setAttribute('width', w);
    step.setAttribute('height', h);
    step.innerHTML = $('#SupportingBeamCrossSectionSVG').html();

document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(step);

var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById(`cont`).querySelector('svg'));

var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasdata;
var image = new Image;
image.src = imgsrc;
image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.id = "imagepng"
  a.innerHTML = "output file, right click - save as since click() won't work in snippet";
  a.download = "output.png";
  a.href = canvasdata;
  document.body.insertBefore(a, document.getElementById(`chartId`));
}
```

I created a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2qvonncx/11/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an SVG element do this.

```
var step = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
```

```js
var   w = 193,
      h = 260;
var ratio = 2
console.log(ratio);
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas1.id = "canvas1";
canvas1.width = w * ratio;
canvas1.height = h * ratio;
document.getElementById('pngcon').appendChild(canvas1);

var svg = document.getElementById(`chartId`).querySelector('svg');

var step = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
    step.id = 'newsvg';
    step.setAttribute('width', w);
    step.setAttribute('height', h);
    step.innerHTML = $('#SupportingBeamCrossSectionSVG').html();

document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(step);

var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('cont').querySelector('svg'));

var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasdata;
var image = new Image;
image.src = imgsrc;
console.log(imgsrc);

image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.id = "imagepng"
  a.innerHTML = "output file, right click - save as since click() won't work in snippet";
  a.download = "output.png";
  a.href = canvasdata;
  document.body.insertBefore(a, document.getElementById(`chartId`));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartId">
<svg id="SupportingBeamCrossSectionSVG" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 193 260" enable-background=" new 0 0 193 260" height="260" width="193" style="max-width: 193px"><path id="SupportingBeamCrossSectionSVG" d="M-36.5,-70 L36.5,-70 L36.5,-63.1 L9.35,-63.1 A7,7 1 0,02.35,-56.1 L2.35,56.1 A7,7 1 0,09.35,63.1 L36.5,63.1 L36.5,70 L-36.5,70 L-36.5,63.1 L-9.35,63.1 A7,7 1 0,0-2.35,56.1 L-2.35,-56.1 A7,7 1 0,0-9.35,-63.1 L-36.5,-63.1 Z" fill="#428bca" transform="translate(96.5, 130)"></path><g fill="#484D61" transform="translate(96.5, 130)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="2"></circle><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="96.5" y2="0" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,5"></line><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="130" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,5"></line><polygon points="96.5,0 86.5,4 86.5,-4"></polygon><polygon points="0,130 -4,120 4,120"></polygon><text x="96.5" y="13.5" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" text-anchor="end">y</text><text x="7.5" y="130" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" text-anchor="start">z</text></g><g id="hSupportingBeam" fill="#484D61" transform="translate(15, 60)"><g transform="translate(0, 70)"><line x1="0" y1="-75" x2="0" y2="75" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-5" y1="-70" x2="5" y2="-70" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-5" y1="70" x2="5" y2="70" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><circle cx="0" cy="-70" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><circle cx="0" cy="70" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><text x="-7.5" y="0" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270, -7.5,0)"><tspan>140.00<tspan dy="3" font-size="10"></tspan></tspan></text></g></g><g id="tfSupportingBeam" fill="#484D61" transform="translate(40, 193.1)"><g transform="translate(0, 3.45)"><line x1="0" y1="-8.45" x2="0" y2="8.45" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-5" y1="-3.45" x2="5" y2="-3.45" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-5" y1="3.45" x2="5" y2="3.45" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><circle cx="0" cy="-3.45" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><circle cx="0" cy="3.45" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><text x="-7.5" y="0" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270, -7.5,0)"><tspan>6.90<tspan dy="3" font-size="10"></tspan></tspan></text></g></g><g id="heSupportingBeam" fill="#484D61" transform="translate(40, 73.9)"><g transform="translate(0, 56.1)"><line x1="0" y1="-61.1" x2="0" y2="61.1" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-5" y1="-56.1" x2="5" y2="-56.1" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-5" y1="56.1" x2="5" y2="56.1" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><circle cx="0" cy="-56.1" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><circle cx="0" cy="56.1" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><text x="-7.5" y="0" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270, -7.5,0)"><tspan>112.20<tspan dy="3" font-size="10"></tspan></tspan></text></g></g><g id="bSupportingBeam" fill="#484D61" transform="translate(60, 40)"><g transform="translate(36.5, 0)"><line x1="-41.5" y1="0" x2="41.5" y2="0" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-36.5" y1="-5" x2="-36.5" y2="5" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="36.5" y1="-5" x2="36.5" y2="5" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><circle cx="-36.5" cy="0" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><circle cx="36.5" cy="0" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><text x="0" y="-7.5" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle"><tspan>73.00<tspan dy="3" font-size="10"></tspan></tspan></text></g></g><g id="twSupportingBeam" fill="#484D61" transform="translate(94.15, 172)"><g transform="translate(2.35, 0)"><line x1="-7.35" y1="0" x2="7.35" y2="0" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="-2.35" y1="-5" x2="-2.35" y2="5" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><line x1="2.35" y1="-5" x2="2.35" y2="5" stroke="#484D61" stroke-width="1"></line><circle cx="-2.35" cy="0" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><circle cx="2.35" cy="0" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><text x="4.7" y="-7.5" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="start"><tspan>4.70<tspan dy="3" font-size="10"></tspan></tspan></text></g></g><g transform="translate(105.85, 73.9)"><circle cx="-4.949747468305833" cy="-4.949747468305833" r="2" fill="#484D61"></circle><polyline fill="none" stroke="#484D61" points="-9.949747468305834,-9.949747468305834 4.949747468305833,9.949747468305834 39.94974746830583,9.949747468305834"></polyline><text x="22.449747468305834" y="3.4497474683058327" fill="#484D61" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle">7.00</text></g></svg>
</div>
<div id="cont"></div>
<div id="pngcon"></div>
```

Comment: In the chartId is the initial SVG image, with the viewbox attribute. In the cont is the new SVG image with the width and height attributes. If you choose the chartId you will see that the final png is distorted and this is the reason I am trying to create a new SVG element.

Comment: I have edited my answer, i thought you were doing this as a workaround.
That's why i left off the creation of a new svg element. Anyway the problem was exactly that. Actually, if i think about it there is no need to create a new svg element. You would just set the width and height attribute of your existing svg element.

Comment: If I set the width and height of the existing svg element it "loses" its responsiveness, and if I set width and height, convert the svg to png and then unset these properties, it is no more visible! createElementNS worked fine! I really really thank you about your time!

Comment: Your welcome. Your right with what you said about keeping the svg element responsive. So your approach is absolutely correct.